# How to put a check on Jquery Data that either the data is in form of JSON or a simple HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to check for the JSON Data.

That if I got a Data in form of JSON

Do this code

Else

This Code.

How can i do this ?

Example Variable for Data in Jquery:

```
data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()` to check it.
Try:

```
try
{
   var json = JSON.parse(your string);
}
catch(e)
{
   //not a json
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hjKDf/)

Comment: Will it work with Invalid Json ? If i received invalid JSON it should fail the check and go to else part

Comment: @CodeHunter , invalid json is treated as non-json data ! You cannot detect invalid json as being json, because it is not !

Comment: @CodeHunter I have made fiddle.

Comment: @CodeHunter yes, it will go to the else part.

Answer (score 0):

add this function to your code:

```
function isJSON(data) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(data);
        return true;
    } catch (ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and simply to use it :

```
if(isJSON(data))
    // it's json, do whatever you want
else
    // it's not json, do whatever you want
```